# Hover an element, add class to another div with same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hover, addclass

I already found a part of my problem but it still needs work.
What i want to achieve is when i hover over a div, others divs should have class added to them if the original class is the same.
So let's start.

I have a menu:

```
<ul id="listz"><li class='has-sub'><a href='/produse/trape-de-fum-si-ventilatie/'><span>Smoke vents</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='/produse/trape-de-fum-si-ventilatie/trape-de-fum/'><span>Trape de fum</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='/rokvent-simplu-canat'>RokVent Simplu canat</a></li>
                                <li><a href='/pheonix-dublu-canat'>Ph&ouml;nix Dublu canat</a></li>
                                <li><a href='/megaphonix'>Megaph&ouml;nix</a></li>
                                <li><a href='/megastar'>MegaStar</a></li>
                                <li><a href='/firefighter'>Firefighter</a></li>
                                <li><a href='/smokejet'>SmokeJet</a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='/multijet'>MultiJet</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class='has-sub'><a href='/produse/trape-de-fum-si-ventilatie/trape-de-ventilatie-si-vizitare/'><span>Trape de ventilatie si vizitare</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='/rokvent-luminatoare-fixe'>RokVent(luminatoare fixe)</a></li>
                                <li class='last'><a href='/rokpas-luminatoare-acces'>RokPas(luminatoare acces)</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li></ul>
```

As you can see i have Parent "Smoke vents" that has children.
The menu is on the left side. On the right side i will have a picture with a warehouse that has smoke vent elements. When you hover over them, they change color.

At that moment the menu needs to open and show the associated product that is in the menu. So when you hover over the element of the warehouse it should add class to the menu so i can change the background and show that that element is that product or products.

One problem is that i need it to match them by class (wich i will make unique by each element).

The second problem is that the menu does not open when i hover over a part of the image. If i have the menu open i can see the highlighted item in the menu.

This is the code that i got now and does the hovering part but only by matching in order.(what i mean is that if i add only to the parents the class it shows right but if i add to a child also then the last parent will not have a addClass):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#listz1 li,#listz2 li").hover(function() {
            var index =  $(this).index();
            $("#listz1, #listz2").each(function() {
                $(".link1",this).eq(index).toggleClass("hoverz");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you make a demo of the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bs3etgay/1/

Comment: i updated http://jsfiddle.net/bs3etgay/2/   as you can see i need it to be associated by class, not by order because then it's not the link that i need. Also is there an option to add a class to the parent and the parent of the parent when it's hovering over child? Since the menu will be closed, when the user hovers over the <li> he will not see it because the menu is closed. It only changes background.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bs3etgay/3/ ?

Comment: yes like that. But can you also help me with the adding the class to the father ul and big father? usually the menu is closed. When you click it, the class open is added to it. So i need it when i hover over it, since the menu is closed, i need it to open and if i hover off it should close. Since the image has an url this means that i just need to show what product name is.